# Как решить проблему с php.ini?

Tags: php, linux, composer

Пытаюсь запустить composer чтобы тот стянул проект, но выходят вот такие ошибки:

> Problem 1
>   - Installation request for erusev/parsedown 1.7.3 -> satisfiable by erusev/parsedown[1.7.3].
>   - erusev/parsedown 1.7.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system. Problem 2
>   - Installation request for laravel/framework v6.4.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.4.0].
>   - laravel/framework v6.4.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system. Problem 3
>   - Installation request for lcobucci/jwt 3.3.1 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[3.3.1].
>   - lcobucci/jwt 3.3.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system. Problem 4
>   - Installation request for league/commonmark 1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/commonmark[1.0.0].
>   - league/commonmark 1.0.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system. Problem 5
>   - Installation request for maknz/slack dev-laravel-any -> satisfiable by maknz/slack[dev-laravel-any].
>   - maknz/slack dev-laravel-any requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system. Problem 6
>   - Installation request for sentry/sentry 2.2.2 -> satisfiable by sentry/sentry[2.2.2].
>   - sentry/sentry 2.2.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system. Problem 7
>   - Installation request for xsolla/xsolla-sdk-php v4.0.2 -> satisfiable by xsolla/xsolla-sdk-php[v4.0.2].
>   - xsolla/xsolla-sdk-php v4.0.2 requires php >=7.1.3 <7.3 -> your PHP version (7.3.12) does not satisfy that requirement. Problem 8
>   - laravel/framework v6.4.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>   - tightenco/ziggy dev-osuweb requires laravel/framework >=5.4@dev -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.4.0].
>   - Installation request for tightenco/ziggy dev-osuweb -> satisfiable by tightenco/ziggy[dev-osuweb].
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
>   - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Comment: Попытка видимо одна была, а out не прочитан.....

Comment: у вас не установлено расширение https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mbstring.installation.php